# How to break on entering and leaving a function in GDB from bpx commands?

Tags: gdb

So when using the GDB prompt I can use `break foobar` to break upon entering function `foobar`. Then I can assign commands to that breakpoint, such as:

```
set $i = 0
commands 1
silent
printf "Before foobar: %d\n", $i
set $i = $i + 1
end
```

However, from these commands how would I proceed until the end of the function (on the prompt it's `finish`) and then simply output another line (`printf "Before foobar: %d\n", $i`) and `continue`.

I tried using this from `.gdbinit`:

```
set $i = 0
commands 1
silent
printf "Before foobar: %d\n", $i
set $i = $i + 1
finish
printf "After foobar: %d\n", $i
end
```

But it simply never prints anything for the second `printf`, presumably because of the "mode" in which GDB is during `commands`.

Can anyone tell me whether what I want is at all possible (GDB version is 7.7.1) and if it is, how to accomplish it?